# A Question on Vector Subspaces on $ℝ^{1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

OK, so I have a question from Steven J. Leon's [Linear Algebra with Applications](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8795347-linear-algebra-with-applications), and an answer to said question.  Unfortunately, I seem to be stumbling on understanding the answer and I was hoping that some kind SE comrade might help set me straight.  So here is the question, answer, and what seems to be bothering me.

Question:

> Prove that if *S* is a subspace of $ℝ^{1}$, then either *S* = {**0**} or *S* = $ℝ^{1}$.

Answer:

> Let *S* $\neq$ {**0**} be a subspace of $ℝ^{1}$ and let *a* be an arbitrary element of $ℝ^{1}$.  If *s* is a non-zero element of *S*, then we can define the scalar $\alpha$ to be the real number *a* / *s*.  Since *S* is a subspace it follows that
>
> > $\alpha$*s* = $\frac{a}{s}$*s* = *a*
>
> is an element of *S*.  Therefore, *S* = $ℝ^{1}$.

I get that I'm probably not seeing something rather simple, but here is what is hanging me up. When I see "$ℝ^{1}$", I'm thinking the *set of all real numbers from* $-\infty$ *to* $\infty$.  However, can't a subset of $ℝ^{1}$ be something like {5.4, 2.009, 3.0}?  The answer just seems to posit that *S* is a spanning set (I think).  Using the technique shown in the answer *S* can be made to equal any number in $ℝ^{1}$, but I would think that S $\neq ℝ^{1}$.

Does this make any sense?  Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: A subspace is by definition a vector space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that a subspace is not just any subset, it's also closed under scalar multiplication and addition.

If it's $\{0\}$ then we are done; otherwise it contains some $x\neq 0$, so $\frac1x\cdot x$ is there, which is $1$, and now it's easy to show that every real numbers is in our subspace by the same trick.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A vector (sub)space $S$ is closed under scalar multiplication with any element of the underlying field (in this case, $\mathbb{R}$ as field $F$, as well as $\mathbb{R}$ the vector space itself). So if $v \in S  \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $\alpha v \in S$ for any $\alpha \in F$. This pretty much tells you right away that it has to be the entire real line, if the subspace isn't $\{0\}$.